# Circumstances where polite form is never used?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

I am trying to understand when plain conjugations should be used in polite speech. My basic understanding is that plain conjugations are always used when they are followed by particular particles, typically when they appear in the middle of phrases, or when they express actions that are themselves objects of a sentence. For example:

> 何かを見たと言っています

(`見た` is in plain form)

or

> それは言うのが難しいです

(`言う` is in plain form)

Is there a rule of thumb to keep in mind when deciding whether the form of verbs should be used in polite speech? It is okay if there is not a surefire answer – any advice would be helpful!

Comment: Um, "formal/informal" is not the right term to distinguish these. You should use "polite/plain". For example laws and academic articles are written with no です/ます, but they are not informal.

Comment: Do you mean you have never come across `〜なければなりません`?

Comment: Updated the question – @aguijonazo I have seen the plain form so many times that I don't recall seeing that form

Comment: You will see the plain form nearly everywhere and in any complex sentence.  Generally, the polite forms will be reserved to the end of a statement--there do seem to be some exceptions to this.  But, you have have an embedded structure, like 本をよんだひと, *folks who read the book*, the *relative clause* will be in plain form.  When you have something like 雨が降ると you'll most likely see plain form.

Comment: If your concern is about being polite, just make sure that you use the polite forms at the end of the sentence.  There are a number of Japanese teachers online who interview others and both parties use polite forms.  So, for example, listen to [Miku Real Japanese when she interviews other Japanese folk](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsQCbl3a9FtYvA55BxdzYiQ) you'll get a good sense of how polite forms are mixed with plain forms.  And you should be able to notice that mostly, polite forms are reserved for the end of sentences.

Comment: Do you mean why the sentences in the question are ok instead of 見ましたと言っています or 言いますのが難しいです? Then a rule of thumb would be _Don't use です/ます twice in a sentence_. (I haven't thought too much about it)

Comment: These comments help a lot, thank you!